# imap_open on server Aruba.it

Tags: imap-open

To receive mail I usually use:

`imap_open('{mail.sito.com:143/notls}', $user, $pass);`

I am having difficulty however when I have to connect to an email on Aruba server.

i tried with:

`{mail.website.com:143}`
`{mail.website.com/pop3:110}`
`{pop3.website.com/pop3:110}`
`{imaps.aruba.it:993}INBOX`
`{imaps.aruba.it:993}`

but it does not open the stream.

Do you know which is the right string to use?

Comment: Improve your question by adding what type of error you get. paste some output of the error output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pop3 protocol with

```
$pop3 = "pop3.yourdomain.ext";
$port = 110;
$inbox = imap_open("{".$pop3.":".$port."/pop3/notls}INBOX", $username, $password);
......
imap_close($inbox);
```

but don't work if Imap is active in Aruba services.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it work :

```
$imap = "imaps.aruba.it";
$port = 993;
$inbox = imap_open("{".$imap.":".$port."/imap4/ssl}INBOX",$username, $password);
......
imap_close($inbox);
```

REMEMBER : you must activate imap extension in your php.ini